# How to find an object which is added to a scene only when game starts?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm looking for some advice how to find an object which is added to scene only when the game starts? Before start it isn't in Scene hierarchy. It's prefab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of the answer of **Philipp** and **Uri Popov**, You need code something like given below(comments for demonstration):

```
    //make a public  static list for saving all the objects ref you are instantiating during runtime
class InstanceManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static List<GameObject> runtimeGameObjectList = List<GameObject>();
}

//where you are currently instantiating 
GameObject g = Instantiate(myPrefab);
// add this line so that instantiated ref save in the list for later use
InstanceManager.runtimeGameObjectList.add(g);
```

Now you can do whatever you want with this list runtimeGameObjectList.

Comment: If all you want is to do something one-off when the game first loads, you don't even need the instance manager, you can just store a reference to the GameObject and change it that way.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a prefab with [`Instantiate`,](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) you receive a reference to that object which you can then pass to where it is needed.

Alternatively, you can search for an object in the scene by its name with [`Find`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) or by a tag with [`FindObjectWithTag`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). But keep in mind that these are not very fast (especially on larger scenes), so you should only do it once and save the result in a variable.

Comment: 25 seconds late..... damn

Answer (score 1):

you can use on of the following :

```
GameObject.Find("name of object");
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("name of the tag of the object")
```

or alternatively you can just keep the reference to the instantiated game object after you create it.

Comment: Does it matter whether the object is (Clone)? for "GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag"

Comment: no. As log as the proper tag is set during instantiation.